# Android Java: SharedPreferences being set but not being read

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, is-empty

My app creates a default `SharedPrferences` for a "default font size" (specifically: `public static final String DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE_KEY = "defaultFontSize";` in my `AppUtils` class) when the app opens.  It seems I am able to create this `SharedPreferences` with default value of 16 and immediately after creating I try to dump all the value keys and nothing is returned.  At this point in the code I have not implemented nor adjusted the value of the font size key, only the first steps - creation and immediately checking via a dump of whether it is stored.  After creating nothing is returned in the dump.

The app `android.intent.action.MAIN` is the `WelcomeActivity` class.  In this class I declare `SharedPreferences` and then initialize with a method call to `AppUtils.initializeSharedPreferences` in `onCreate`:

```
...
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        AppUtils.initializeSharedPreferences(this);
        sharedPreferences = AppUtils.getSharedPreferences();
...
```

The method `initializeSharedPreferences` is only called one time and *should* be creating the `DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE_KEY`, thus creating a `SharedPreference` if none exists, here is that method which is in the `AppUtils` class:

```
    public static void initializeSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null) {
            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("SongTrackerApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (getDefaultFontSize(sharedPreferences) == 0) {
                saveDefaultFontSize(sharedPreferences, 16);
            }
            Log.d("AdjustTextSize", "(AppUtils) INIT: line #17, 1st Value-DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE_KEY: " + getDefaultFontSize(sharedPreferences));
        }
        Log.d("AdjustTextSize", "(AppUtils) INIT: line #19, DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE_KEY: " + getDefaultFontSize(sharedPreferences) + ", context: " + context);
    }
```

Also inside the `onCreate` within the `WelcomeActivity` class I get the value for the `DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE_KEY` and then call a method to dump all the SharedPreferences (see `dbHelper.logSharedPreferencesEntries`):

```
        // Get all key-value pairs from SharedPreferences
        if (sharedPreferences != null) {
            // Print out all sharedPreferences:
            Log.d("AdjustTextSize", "(WelcomeActivity) line #77, DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE_KEY: " + AppUtils.getDefaultFontSize(sharedPreferences));
            dbHelper.logSharedPreferencesEntries(sharedPreferences, "WelcomeActivity");
        }
```

The `Log.d` indicates that there is in fact a `SharedPreferences` for `DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE_KEY`:

```
(WelcomeActivity) line #77, DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE_KEY: 16.0
```

At this point in the code I am still in the `Main` activity and call a method in `DatabaseHelper` class (`dbHelper.logSharedPreferencesEntries`) to dump all the `SharedPreferences` however NOTHING is returned.  Here is the method `logSharedPreferencesEntries` which returns 'true' for `if (allEntries.isEmpty()) ...`:

```
    public void logSharedPreferencesEntries(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String pageName) {
        Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPreferences.getAll();
        // Check if there are any entries
        if (allEntries.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("AdjustTextSize", "(DBHelper via: " + pageName + ") DUMP line #1063 No sharedPreference keys found");
            return;
        }
        // Iterate through the entries and log them
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            // Display constant name, key name, and value in Log.d
            String constantName = findConstantName(key);
            Log.d("AdjustTextSize", "(DBHelper via: " + pageName + ") DUMP line #1072 - Constant: " + constantName + ", Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value.toString());
        }
    }
```

I have researched other related entries within stackoverflow, although many related issues to `SharedPreferences` many are dated going back to 2012 - nothing recent seems to address my 2023 problem.

Thank you in advance for reviewing and commenting.

**EDIT: 12.14.2023 In response to @ltp**

Thank you @ltp I replaced `editor.apply();` with `editor.commit();` the latter your suggestion and which works synchronously thus I should be seeing the impact directly as opposed to the asynchronous `apply()`.  Curious as I am setting a `SharedPreferences` in the `initializeSharedPreferences` method:

```
    public static void initializeSharedPreferences(Context context) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null) {
            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("SongTrackerApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (getDefaultFontSize(sharedPreferences) == 0) {
                saveDefaultFontSize(sharedPreferences, 16);
            }
        }
    }
```

and next line of code after the call to `initializeSharedPreferences` is the method 'dumping' all `SharedPreferences` - even with `commit()` I still get the `Log.d` "No sharedPreference keys found" - and I know in the previous line it was set.  If I change the text size using what I programmed into the app's code, after about 2-3 attempts I DO see the 'dump' method displaying `Constant: DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE_KEY, Key: defaultFontSize, Value: 0.0` but the font size is not accurate, I believe that is a separate issue so will ignore for present.  Curious about any other comments please!

Comment: Did you call/use commit() in `saveDefaultFontSize` ?

Comment: no I didn't and I believe that is the problem!  Please address this as a solution.

Comment: Thank you @ltp I replaced `editor.apply();` with `editor.commit();` ... since my  response is too long I will append to my original query above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using  [SharedPreferences.Editor.apply()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply()), replace it with  [SharedPreferences.Editor.commit()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#commit()). Quoting from the doc:

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent
> storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory
> SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to
> disk and you won't be notified of any failures